# py2exe: run the compiled .exe, got error: type object 'pandas._libs.tslib._TSObject' has no attribute...__'

Tags: python, pandas, py2exe

I use py2exe to compile python script. The python script runs without any error before compiling.

below is the setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os 
import matplotlib
import numpy
from glob import glob

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

datafiles = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_99b61f5e8371c1d4\*.*'))]
datafiles.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())

setup(windows=['Run.py'], data_files= datafiles, options={"py2exe": {"includes": ["matplotlib"]}})
```

In the run.py, I imported pandas. Pandas is used in a function as below

```
import pandas

def PossDist(Iterations, AssumptionFolder, ResultFolder, SampledResult):
    SampledLoss = pandas.read_csv(SampledResult)
    d= pandas.pivot_table(...)

The compile finished successfully without error.
```

When I run the compiled run.exe, I got error as below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Run.py", line 6, in 
  File "xlwings__init__.pyc", line 34, in

File "xlwings\main.pyc", line 1727, in

File "xlwings\conversion__init__.pyc", line 3, in

File "pandas__init__.pyc", line 26, in 
    Main Features
  File "pandas_libs__init__.pyc", line 4, in

File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyc", line 12, in

File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyc", line 10, in __load

File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyx", line 1514, in init pandas._libs.tslib
AttributeError: type object 'pandas._libs.tslib._TSObject' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'

Anyone have any clue?

Is there other way to let others run my python script on pc without python installed?

Thanks,

Comment: I tried PyInstaller-3.3.1, got the same error message. Even after I comment out lines with Pandas, and compile again, I still got the same error message